# What would be a good wide angle lens to rent for Nikon?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, wide-angle, renting

I have a Nikon D5000, and am looking to rent a wide angle lens for a day. Any suggestions as what should be a good lens to try out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two main WIDE options for DX are the Nikon 10-24mm f/3.5-4.5 and Tokina 11-16mm f/2.8. Since the D5000 doesn't have an autofocus screw the Tokina would have to be focused manually (easier with the depth of field available at these really wide angles). I have the Tokina for my D90 and it's a great lens.

Comment: 10-24mm Nikkor lens is loads of fun. Like any wide lens, it's harder to use than you would expect because creatively, wide lenses push things away and make everything small. To counteract this you must proactively get really close to your subjects and have backgrounds clear of distractions. But if you do, the results can be breathtaking.

Comment: Shooting an ultra-wide is challenging. I got the Tokina to get a taste for something beyond 18mm and you really have to wrap your head around what happens when you go that wide. The perspective distortion can do some cool things, but it takes practice to get use to it.

Comment: Or the 10.5mm DX fisheye.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how wide you want to go and whether you have a full-frame or cropped-sensor body, but you probably can't go wrong with the highly-praised [14-24mm f/2.8](http://www.borrowlenses.com/product/nikon_wide_angle/Nikon_14-24_2.8)

Comment: Indeed, seems like a great lens. I better take the _insurance_ with it :)

Comment: That's a full-frame lens, not wide at all when used on a DX body such as the D5000.

Comment: Thanks Julio. I will most likely go for  Nikon 10-24mm f/3.5-4.5 then.

Comment: @Julio The fact it was a D5000 camera wasn't included in the question at the time I answered.

Comment: It was. Please look at the revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Tokina 11-16mm f/2.8 is a wonderful lens. Also you could try the Sigma 10-20 f/4-5.6 . Then there is the Nikon. But personally i prefer the Tokina just because of the f/2.8. Also you could consider a couple of fish eye's. They have a wonderful effect. Maybe the Nikon 16mm f/2.8.

Comment: For the D5000 you'd want the 10.5DX fisheye, though autofocus would not be supported.

Answer (score 2):

The Sigma 8mm is considered one of the best wide lenses you can shoot. All you have to do is figure out how to keep your feet out of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

The older (than the 10-24) Nikkor 12-24 f4 DX could also be an option. I own this lens and am very happy with it (D80 and D7000). It is tack sharp.

I have never compared it with the 10-24, but from a little (very little) Google research, the 12-24 might be the slightly better performer and of better build quality. The latter may not be of interest to you, though, since you'll be renting it.

Answer (score 1):

The Sigma 8-16mm lens is excellent and really sharp - it's not a FF lens, but should work fine with the D5000 1.5x crop factor.

Sigma also makes a 12-24mm FF lens if you think you might get a larger body in the future, and they also make a 10-20 mm lens - though I don't think that lens is as good as the 8-16mm lens.

Comment: The sigma 8-16mm quickly became one of my favorite lenses.  Most of my photographs are of landscapes and lens can take in the whole view.